# How can i inject Unity dependency to any my class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

In ASP.NET MVC5 i just have class **Saver**

```
 public class Saver
 {
    private readonly ResponseModel _model;

    [Dependency]
    public SomeService SomeService { get; set; }


    public Saver(ResponseModel model)
    {
        _model= estateModel;
    }

    public void Save(){
        // here SomeService is null
    }        
 }
```

In UnityConfig.cs I have this

`container.RegisterType<SomeService >(new TransientLifetimeManager());`

Then in UnityMvcActivator.cs i have this

```
        IUnityContainer container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

        FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

What can I do to resolve this error. Why inject work in controller, but don't  in other classes, which isn't a controller?